# AES- ECB using DataPower

Tags: encryption, aes, ibm-datapower

I have a requirement where in I get a HEX string which is 32 character long. I need to encrypt it with AES-128-ECB and get an Hex string with is again 32 character long.

I have been asked to convert the 32 char hex string to binary stream(to get 16 bytes of data) and then encrypt it using AES-ECB(to get 16 bytes of encrypted data) and then convert this 16 bytes of encrypted data to 32 char hex string.

I came across this article to achieve AES-ECB encryption. 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/HermannSW/entry/gatewayscript_modules_aes?lang=en
​

Kindly let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the actual code you have the concept, for more detailed help you will need to make a best-effort attempt and add that code to the question along with error information and input/output test data (in hex).

Note that you need to ensure that padding is not added, some AES implementations add padding by default and will add a block of (PKCS#7) padding to data that is an exact multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES).

> Note: ECB mode, it is insecure when the key is used more than once and there is a similarity in the data. See [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.